# Django Model for defining a relationship between two other models and filtering later

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

So am designing a REST API for a mobile blogging app, in which am trying to implement an upvote feature for the blog posts where what i want to implement is:

Whenever a user *U* upvotes a particular blog *B* the client will send a POST request (with username and the blog name) which will define a relationship between them in the Database, so that later when the client wants to know that if a particular user has upvoted a particular blog or not, it can get to know by making a GET request through some filering.

I have tried to create Vote model, in which i define a ManyToMany relationship with both, user and the blog post ( see the Vote Model below for better understanding)

here are my models,

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.TextField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

```
class Post(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200) # the name of the blog
    #some other stuff like body of the blog
    .
    .
    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

The Vote model,

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    post = models.ManyToManyField(Post)

    def __str__(self):
        return ("%s %s" %(self.user, self.post))
```

This does not do the job well, e.g.,

- It requires the URL of the users and blog post(see below point) in the POST request rather than just the names of each, because of the ManyToMany Relationship.
- Even if we ignore the above issue and make the following POST requests with form data **two** times:

```
  {
    "user" = [
         "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/1/"
     ],
    "post" = [
         "http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/1/"
     ],
  }
```

*It creates 2 entries in the database.*

**And further I still cant figure out how the filtering will work out, i.e. how the client side application will get to know whether there is a relationship between the user and the blog post through a GET request.**

I think this is a pretty bad design.

Please suggest a better alternative or improvement(if possible) in my current design.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Vote` as the [**`through=…`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) of a many-to-many between `Post` and `User`, or even just let Django construct the many-to-many model, since here you did not define an extra field.

You thus can define a method like:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200) # the name of the blog
    # …
    voted_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='voted_posts')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

For the given `Post` primary key, and the given `User` primary key, you can then create a vote with:

```
Post.voted_users.through.objects.create(
    post_id=post_pk,
    user_id=user_pk
)
```

You thus can for example develop a serializer that works on the `Post.voted_users.through` model, and that has two `ForeignKey`s: one to the `Post` model and one to the `User` model.

Comment: suppose if another user likes the post, how will you update the Database?
i tried doing that, if we do POST req two times with different  usernames, it creates 2 entries with the same blog name, again wastage of data.

Comment: @sweetsecret: no, this is the way to deal with a m2m relation in a relational database: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model) Note that the through model does *not* store the blog *name* or user *name* it stores the primary keys, which are normally ints (especially in Django it is a good idea to make the primary keys uniform).

Comment: Something like an "array" is not supported by all relational databases, but even if it is, it does not guarantee referential integrity, indexes, etc. (or at least not in a standardized way).